# oracle odbc driver configuration

Tags: oracle11g, odbc

I'm having a problem with configuring oracle odbc

the dialog page is blank

when I enter TNS name as : XE

I get the following error:

unable to connect SQLState=08004

my tnsnames file is:

```
KPI_SERVER= 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost)(PORT =1521)) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE) 
    ) 
  )
```

the connection is successful in SQL developer by the following data:

hostname: localhost
port number: 1521
service: XE

and the trns_admin variable is set to: C:\oracle_odbc\tnsnames

Path is set to: C:\oracle_odbc

what did I do wrong?

thank you for your time

Comment: the test that you have made with sqldeveloper don't use tnsnames.ora. Can you try specifying connection type tns and using the name KPI_SERVER?

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain more.. what do you mean by connection type
the KPI_SERVER was in a video that I saw to set the connect but to be honest I don't understand a single line of the code written there

Comment: In your computer find sqlplus.exe (there is in oracle installation directory). Open this directory with command prompt and launch 'sqlplus.exe <dbuser>/<dbpassword>@KPI_SERVER. If the tnsnames.ora is correct you connect into db an you can launch a select (ex: Select * from user_tables)

Comment: I got this error: ORA-12154: TNS : could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: from dos command launch 'echo %TNS_ADMIN%', the output maybe C:\oracle_odbc\tnsnames. The directory C:\oracle_odbc\tnsnames contain the file tnsnames.ora? Check with dos command dir (sometimes the files have a double extension)

Comment: I couldn't find the file tnsnames.ora ! why it is in C:\oracle_odbc ?

Comment: in your question: 'my tnsnames file is', what is the name and the path of this file?

Comment: Question: C:\oracle_odbc\tnsnames is a file or a directory?

Answer (score 1):

We try to make order: open a command prompt,

launch `echo %TNS_ADMIN%` the result is `C:\oracle_odbc\`?

launch `dir C:\oracle_odbc\`, the result is `tnsnames.ora`?

launch `type C:\oracle_odbc\tnsnames.ora` the result is the content of "my tnsnames file is" section of your initial post?

If all the response are yes, can you retry to lauch `'sqlplus.exe dbuser/dbpassword@KPI_SERVER`

Comment: I followed each step mentioned above and I still get the following error: ORA-12154: TNS : could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: from cmd when I typed : sqlplus.exe dbuser/dbpassword@KPI_SERVER

Comment: Ok. I doin't see your response. The result of command 'echo %TNS_ADMIN%' is 'C:\oracle_odbc\'? The result of command 'dir C:\oracle_odbc\' is 'tnsnames.ora'?

Comment: yes exactly.. what did you think is the problem and thank you for your time

Comment: Try .... edit the file C:\oracle_odbc\tnsnames.ora, put all content into a single line in this way: KPI_SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT =1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE))) -- No space, no return, nothing! Save the file and launch 'sqlplus.exe dbuser/dbpassword@KPI_SERVER'

Comment: same thing ! what I did was I run the sql command line and I typed: connect dbuser/dbpassword@KPI_SERVER'  and I got same error , I don't know if that would make any difference

Comment: Try the command 'tnsping KPI_SERVER' and put all the output here

Comment: used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora
TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

Comment: In the folder C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\ there is a file tnsnames.ora? If yes, add 'KPI_SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT =1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE)))' at the end of the file and relaunch 'tnsping KPI_SERVER', put all the output here

Comment: I did find the file and changed it as you mentioned  but same error :(

Comment: Write the output of tnsping

Comment: used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora
TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

Comment: your system seem don't view the tnsnames.ora file, put all the content of C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora here

Comment: XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = RUHB-LAP-2102)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

Comment: ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  ) 
  KPI_SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT =1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE)))

Comment: in your system there is the alias XE that is created at installation time (i suppose). If you try 'tnsping XE' it works? if yes, you can use this alias in your odbc?

Comment: useing command $tnsping XE I got:

used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias 
attempting to contact ......

does that means it works? 

and how can I use it to set the connection?

Comment: The tnsping successfully contact the server?

Comment: I got the following output: used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias 
attepting to contact(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=GLORY)(PORT =1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (90 msec)

Comment: OK, the connection works! Now, you must configure your odbc using the alias name XE

Comment: I entered XE as the TNS name and the user ID & password and I got this error : unable to connect SQLState=08004

Comment: When you try to configure oracle odbc and select the driver, you have only one version of driver? What version e what vendor?

Comment: I have 2 versions  32 bit & 64 bit my machine is 64

Comment: Look here, maybe a driver problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798486/oracle-odbc-driver-configuration/34806456?noredirect=1#comment57407155_34806456. Why you are creating an odbc connection, is possible to use another type of connection?

Comment: the link is not working , can you re-post it please? when I run phpinfo I can't find ocI8 package can you please explain to me how can I install the package for windows 64 bit?